# Airflow2 gitSync DAG works for airflow namespace, but not alternate namespace

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, airflow-2.x, gitops

I'm running minikube to develop with Apache Airflow2. I am trying to sync my DAGs from a private repo on GitLab, but have taken a few steps back just to get a basic example working. In the case of the default "airflow" namespace, it works, but when using the exact same file in a non-default name space, it doesn't.

I have a values.yaml file which has the following section:

```
dags:
  gitSync:
    enabled: true
    repo: "ssh://git@github.com/apache/airflow.git"
    branch: v2-1-stable
    rev: HEAD
    depth: 1
    maxFailures: 0
    subPath: "tests/dags"
    wait: 60
    containerName: git-sync
    uid: 65533
    extraVolumeMounts: []
    env: []
    resources: {}
```

If I run `helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow -f values.yaml -n airflow`, and then `kubectl port-forward svc/airflow-webserver 8080:8080 --namespace airflow`, I get a whole list of DAGs as expected at http://localhost:8080.

But if I run `helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow -f values.yaml -n mynamespace`, and then `kubectl port-forward svc/airflow-webserver 8080:8080 --namespace mynamespace`, I get no DAGs listed at http://localhost:8080.

This post would be 10 times longer if I listed all the sites I hit trying to resolve this. What have I done wrong??

UPDATE: I created a new namespace, `test01`, in case there was some history being held over and causing the problem. I ran `helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow -f values.yaml -n test01`. Starting the webserver and inspecting, I do not get a login screen, but it goes straight to the usual web pages, also does not show the dags list, but this time has a notice at the top of the DAG page:

> The scheduler does not appear to be running.
> The DAGs list may not update, and new tasks will not be scheduled.

This is different behaviour yet again (although the same as with `mynamespace` insofar as showing no DAGs via gitSync), even though it seems to suggest a reason why DAGs aren't being retrieved in this case. I don't understand why a scheduler isn't running if everything was spun-up and initiated the same as before.

Curiously, `helm show values apache-airflow/airflow --namespace test01 > values2.yaml` gives the default `dags.gitSync.enabled: false` and `dags.gitSync.repo: https://github.com/apache/airflow.git`. I would have thought that should reflect what I upgraded/installed  from values.yaml: enable = true and the *ssh* repo fetch. I get no change in behaviour by editing values2.yaml to `dags.gitSync.enabled: true` and re-upgrading -- still the error note about scheduler no running, and no DAGs.